# Apache web server SSI and Jetty

Tags: java, apache, jetty, ssi

I am trying to use Apache mod_include for SSI. I have a java application that is being served currently with Jetty. I have been able to get SSI working directly with Jetty but I'm now trying to have SSI enabled via Apache.

I am using mod_proxy to forward requests to Jetty. I assume I'm missing something here as even though the requests do forward to Jetty, the SSI tags are not being evaluated by Apache.

Current mod_proxy conf

ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

```
ProxyStatus On
<Location /status>
    SetHandler server-status

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>

<Proxy *>
  AddDefaultCharset off
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass    /prototypeWebApp    http://localhost:8080/prototypeWebApp
#ProxyPassReverse    /prototypeWebApp    http://localhost:8080/prototypeWebApp
```

Under webapp directory I have a single file apacheSSI.shtml with the following contents:

```
<!--#include virtual="/prototypeWebApp/apacheSSI.html" -->
```